# onClick in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need catch a onclick event on a button added in my ListView. I am using an Adapter for my ListView.

This is my code.

```
 ImageButton s = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.maketext(this,"Clicked.!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But doesn't work.

Any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460368/handling-imagebutton-clicks-inside-a-custom-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Help.

I could fix this way.

```
 holder.share.setFocusable(false);
    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.maketext(this,"Clicked.!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And this is my Holder Class.

```
 static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView short_notice;
    public ImageButton share;
}
```

Hope it helps...!

Thanks for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your custom adapter, passing the context of your app as argument to set the click:

```
listView.setAdapter(new PesquisaAdapter(this, anunciantescidades, this);
```

Then, in the constructor of your adapter you will have a OnClickListener to recieve the argument `this` (context) that you passed:

```
public PesquisaAdapter(Context context, List<Anunciante> anunciantes, OnClickListener onClick1)
```

In the getView method of the adapter, you can set onClickListener of the button:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton ) v.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClick1);
}
```

In your java, you can implements onClickListener, and then do what you want with your button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(yourbutton.getId() == v.getId()){    
        final int position = listView.getPositionForView((LinearLayout)v.getParent());            
        Toast.maketext(this,"Clicked on position " + position + ".!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, Adapter has a method getContext(), there is no need to pass it.